# can not get the same file numbers in two ways

Tags: r

There are three disk in my computer,c: \d: \e:.
i list all files by two ways ,get different result,what is the matter?

```
list.files("c:/",recursive=TRUE)->x1
list.files("d:/",recursive=TRUE)->x2
list.files("e:/",recursive=TRUE)->x3
print(c(length(x1),length(x2),length(x3)))
[1] 86467     2   832
sapply(c("c:/","d:/","e:/"),function(y){length(list.files(y,recursive=TRUE))})
  c:/   d:/   e:/ 
86470     2   832
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is running and creating files on your c:/ drive. Might even be your R session storing the output of each `list.files` in a temporary file! Three calls, three files...

As an extra hint, you could store the output of `list.files("c:/", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)` twice and use `setdiff` to find the name and location of the extra file(s).